# The amount received being less than the amount required

Tags: banking, international-transfer

I live  in Europe and  I ordered a product from a Moroccan company.  They asked from me to transfer the money to the company bank account in Morocco, which  I did.

Shortly thereafter, a company agent notified me by e-mail that they had provided the wrong bank, that they need to send me a refund,  and that I would have to transfer money to a French bank.

One month later I received the refund but default charges were applied in the amount  of 240 euro (exchange rate, fees, service bank fee).

I sent an  e-mail to the company, asking them  to refund  all charges because this was not my mistake.

What else do I  need to do?

Thank you very much.

---

thank you very much for your answer

I apologies that  i did not mentioned  France company, because is other company name, not same. Actually they are 2 companies in one. One in morocco (production and marketing), else in France Warehouse ( shipping goods.) from France send over the world. 
so, they said : was mistake. we cant accept money transfer here (morocco). when you received the amount, you need to transfer to France company.

Actually this is The first time I deal with the brand (it is international company), 
yeah i received the amount 3 weeks ago, the payment to France not yet, I stopped my order because i need to find the solution for this problem !  until now 2 weeks I am waiting  the answer on my email about this matter

Comment: That sounds dodgy - perhaps consider buying the product elsewhere if possible. Also, if you have not transferred the payment to their French account yet - use that as a negotiating tactic, i.e get them to reduce the price by 240 euro. Most businesses that sell stuff should accept credit card payments (PayPal would be even better) - be wary of just using a bank transfer, it's very hard to get your money back if something goes wrong. Instead of them sending the money back,  it maybe would have been better to get  _your_ bank to reverse the initial transfer - that may have resulted in lower fees.

Comment: Yes I think very good idea to reduce the price by 240 euro, by the way i don't think so that scams, i was in physical store not virtual version, and my case that company is famous, Will not accept the bad reputation of the brand.

My problem if the company don't want to pay what can i do? How to Deal? 
CFPB (consumer finance protection bureau) could to help? Its purpose is to help consumers avoid and fight back against unfair, deceptive or abusive financial practices, but i think only in USA!.

Comment: About  your question :: yes i asked this from my bank, but they said cant to find the money, dont have the possibility for this.
I sent an email immediately to the company and i asked them where is the money? they replied: it is totally normal to transfer the amount to the bank of France first ( for the currency (€) )  
So they transferred money to France, after 10 days to my country.

Answer (score 2):

It seems dodgy for the company to transfer the money from their Moroccan account to their French account via your account when you've already paid in full and in accordance with their original instructions.

You didn't say whether the payment to France has been paid yet. If you were waiting for the refund to be processed before making the payment, try getting the company to agree that whatever refund you received (after fees, exchange rates, etc), you would simply forward to their French account, with all the further related fees and charges taken from the same amount.

It seems fair that **the company** bears the extra costs since they made the mistake.

Comment: Money forwarding typically means scam. Best not to forward the money to French account, not to deal with this company, and not to spend the refund, expecting the money to disappear. At best, this is inept business. At worst, these are scammers.

Comment: I don't think so they are scammers, because I was there at the company store last mai, i looked around the products, and i tried also. we talked about the business. they have stores in morocco and around the world in europe, asia, middle east and australia, i know the owner of the company is famous. but what happned is not profesionel.